# Anyone has used LabView-ROS Toolkit?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am trying to connect labview with ros using labview-ros toolkit from clear path robotics.i am trying ro run inbuilt example of joystick demo.vi...but i got error-56 in labview....i think it is not able to publish data to given ros-ip......anyone know how to solve this problem.

thanking you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74098/anyone-has-used-labview-ros-toolkit?/) by [pavanpatel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5686/pavanpatel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-08-21

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am also testing the toolkit in few hours ago. At the moment, I have successfully connected the toolkit to the Rosbridge in ROS by looking at no error status in Labview but have not transfer any data yet. Have you installed the Rosbridge package in ROS? What IP did you put in the string? What is the explanation of error 56?

---

Originally posted by [clonzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5689/clonzz/) with karma: 60 on 2013-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavanpatel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5686/pavanpatel/) on 2013-09-03**:
yes i have installed rosbridge package.......i have given the ip on which ros is running.......plz tell me how can i solve it.....right now i am getting error 62....... error 62 is that the VI that opened the connection has finished executing and has closed, when a VI finishes executing in LabVIEW the resources are automatically closed to ensure any open resources arn't left dangling.

**Comment by [DavidSuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/3574/davidsuh/) on 2013-09-18**:
I get the same error 62. it's been a week for me to try to solve this issue, but still no idea yet.

**Comment by [jimc91](https://answers.ros.org/users/45049/jimc91/) on 2020-10-08**:
Has anyone sorted this issue, I have a similar issue...